# How can I convert a string to a list in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have :

```
my_args = ["QA-65"]
```

as the desired result,

but in my function, I have:

```
            m = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+-\d+)",line)
            print 'printing m.group(1)'
            print m.group(1)
            m_args = m.group(1)
            print 'my_args '
            print m_args
            print type(m_args)
```

so that the type of "m_args" is string, i.e

How can I convert m_args to a list with just one element with the same content as the string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
my_args = [my_args]
```

Comment: >>> txt = "hello"
>>> txt_list = list(txt)
>>> type(txt_list)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(txt)
<type 'str'>
>>>

Comment: As `str` is iterable, `list(txt)` will return a list containing an element for each element in `txt`.

Answer (score 3):

You do it this way:

```
m_args = [m_args, ]
```

Comment: Note that the comma is optional for creating lists [a,] but is required for tuples (a,)